# Covid-19 available resources

Tags: dataset

I don't even know if this is the best place to ask it but, as a statistics community think somebody here may know something. I am wondering what kind of databases and data are actually available regarding covid-19 infection, especially epidemiological and clinical characteristics.

Is there any source that published available characteristics/clinical data for the  affected patients?

I tried to search the web for it but found no actual downloadable DB or similar

Thank you so much in advance fro any help